# AutoHotKey: Accessing an array of coordinates

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

In AutoHotKey, I've defined a global array as:

```
tab_index_array := []
```

Further down in the script I call a function to build the table:

```
BuildTabIndexArray()
{
  global

  ; coords of each of the 8 selectable tabs on screen
  tab_index_array.Push(332,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(378,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(433,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(486,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(557,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(611,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(685,490)
  tab_index_array.Push(745,490)
}
```

This seems pretty straight forward to me, however, when I'm trying to access this table, all I ever get is blank (empty) values.

```
ClickTab(which_tab)
{
  global

  coords_ := []
  tab_str := tab_index_array[which_tab]

  stringsplit, coords_, tab_str, ","

  x_ := coords_[1]
  y_ := coords_[2]

  SplashTextOn,,, %x_% "`n" %y_% 
  SetTimer, KillSplashText, -5000

  ;SetMouseDelay, slow_click_wait_time
  ;SendEvent {click, %x_%, %y_%}
  ;SetMouseDelay, click_wait_time
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is grab the coordinates out of the array and feed them to the SendEvent command. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated as I've been fighting this for some time now.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to store a string in each of the fields of `tab_index_array`, you need to put it in quotes, like

```
tab_index_array.Push("332,490")
```

Function calls and definitions, which includes `if()`, `.push()`, `strLen()` and so on, work just like functions work in other programming languages, too. You can only leave aside quotes in most AutoHotkey commands which is quite comfortable but confusing sometimes.

Further information can also be found at http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm